# jquery fadein move from links to right

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a[href*="section"]').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);
                $('#sectionCon > div').removeAttr("style");
                    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
                $(addressValue).fadeIn(1500); 
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 2500,'easeInOutExpo',function(){

                });
             });
        });
    </script>
```

Can someone help me. I want to fade $(addressValue) from right to left. This is displayed:none to begin. I have tried animate but that doesnt work as expected

Comment: Would it be possible to post the corresponding CSS and HTML here? It would be easier to understand this question if the rest of the HTML code was visible here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Javascript animation library (GSAP)](http://www.greensock.com/). In my experience, it is very useful and would be perfect for what you are trying to do with minimal coding. You will want to do something like this:

```
doAnimation = function() {
    var image = $('#myImage');
    var t1 = new TimelineMax();
    t1.to(image, 5, {opacity:0, marginLeft: '-300px', ease:Power1.easeOut});
}
```